# Hiding rows with blank cell in column E

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hide, isnull

I am very new to using scripts in Google Sheets, but found this simple and useful piece of code online. I am trying to hide rows in a specific range (rows 10 - 34) where the cells in column E are blank. The code below seems to hide all rows in the range regardless, even those that have a number in column E.

I have tried:

```js
data[i][3] = 'null', 
data[i][4] = 'null', 
data[i][5] = 'null'
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks so much for any help.

```js
function filterRows() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Print Client Report");
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i = 9; i < 34; i++) {
      //If column E (5th column) is "Y" then hide the row.
      if(data[i][3] = 'null') {
        sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Hiding rows where column E is null in rows 10 through 34

```
function filterRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Print Client Report");
  var data = sheet.getRange(10, 1, 25, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  data.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!r[4]) {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 10);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much Cooper, this seems to work!